# initialise jquery datatable with json data and derived columns

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables

Do we have an option in datatable wherein we can derive a column from value of another column:

My current code:

```
customerDataTable = $('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "aaData" : customerData,
            "aoColumns" : [{"mDataProp":"id"},{"mDataProp":"card_id"},{"mDataProp":"points"},{"mDataProp":"name"},{"mDataProp":"ref"},{"mDataProp":"refs"},{"mDataProp":"address"},{"mDataProp":"mob"},{"mDataProp":"ref_mob"},{"mDataProp":"profile"},{"mDataProp":"vitems"},{"mDataProp":"edit"},{"mDataProp":"del"},{"mDataProp":"bills"},{"mDataProp":"account"}],
            /*"columnDefs" : [{orderable:false,targets : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]},{searchable:false,targets:[2,3,4,5,6,7]}],*/
            "sDom" : "<'dt-top-row'Tlf>r<'dt-wrapper't><'dt-row dt-bottom-row'<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p>>",
            "oTableTools" : {
                "aButtons" : ["copy", "print", {
                    "sExtends" : "collection",
                    "sButtonText" : 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                    "aButtons" : ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }],
                "sSwfPath" : "<?=$baseUrl?>static/js/plugin/datatables/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
                $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
                });
            }
        });
```

If i have a data-column "id" in json, can i use it to define columns in below manner:

```
"aoColumns" : [{"mDataProp":"id"},{"mDataProp":"<button onclick='editRecord({id})'>Edit</button>"}],
```

Currently i have manipulated JSON to add a new field edit derived from id, can this be done through dataTable definition

Answer (score 0):

try to use this way :

```
 "aoColumns" : [
      {"mDataProp":"id"},
      {"mDataProp":"<button onclick='editRecord({id})'>Edit</button>",
       "fnRender": function (oObj) {
           if (oObj.aData[0] == "1") // its containg your Id
           { return '<button onclick="editRecord({'+oObj.aData[0]+'})">Edit</button>';}
       }
    ],
```